# How to split pandas dataframe column in different rows based on some condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to split one pandas DataFrame column into multiple rows.

**DATA:** Input dataframe will look like below:

```
sports_name,player_name,player_country,player_average
football,XYZ,US,"[['1', '62.58'], ['2', '25.34'],['3', '88.35'],['4', '59.39']]"
football,ABC,US,"[['1', '56.61'], ['2', '52.63'],['3', 'NA'],['4', '44.32'],['5', '39.69']]"
cricket,PQR,IND,"[['1', '98.73'], ['2', '72.62'],['3', '71.53'],['4', '73.72']]"
cricket,LMN,IND,"[['1', '72.52'], ['2', '71.82'],['3', '-'],['4', '62.72'],['5', '73.83']]"
```

**DATA INFORMATION:**

1. The column which we need to split into multiple rows is **player_average**.
2. This "Player_average" column contains string value which is list of multiple lists.
3. The list will always be contains two values. First is "player_match" and second one is "player_average".
4. The "player_average" value may contains "NA" or "-" or something else.

**Requirement:**

1. "minimum_average" is one integer value.
2. I want the average of each player match which is greater than "minumum_average".

**Output:** The output dataframe should look like below

```
sports_name,player_name,player_country,player_match,player_average
football,XYZ,US,1,62.58
football,XYZ,US,3,88.35
football,XYZ,US,4,59.39
football,ABC,US,1,56.61
football,ABC,US,2,52.63
cricket,PQR,IND,1,98.73
cricket,PQR,IND,2,72.62
cricket,PQR,IND,3,71.53
cricket,PQR,IND,4,73.72
cricket,LMN,IND,1,72.52
cricket,LMN,IND,2,71.82
cricket,LMN,IND,4,62.72
cricket,LMN,IND,5,73.82
```

**EDIT:**

Make sure that data is very huge data. It may contains ~20,000 arrays in "player_average" and ~10,00,000 rows.

Comment: You should try a divide a conquer approach, first split the columns into more columns (separate after each comma and bracket if you want and extract (filter) only the columns you want). Secondly, you melt the columns into rows with [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html)

Comment: I believe my answer below addressed your question.

Answer (score 1):

Say you start with

```
import ast
as_lists = pd.concat(
    [df, pd.DataFrame(df.player_average.apply(ast.literal_eval).tolist())],
    axis=1).drop('player_average', axis=1)
>>> as_lists
    sports_name player_name player_country  0   1   2   3   4
0   football    XYZ US  [1, 62.58]  [2, 25.34]  [3, 88.35]  [4, 59.39]  None
1   football    ABC US  [1, 56.61]  [2, 52.63]  [3, NA] [4, 44.32]  [5, 39.69]
2   cricket PQR IND [1, 98.73]  [2, 72.62]  [3, 71.53]  [4, 73.72]  None
3   cricket LMN IND [1, 72.52]  [2, 71.82]  [3, -]  [4, 62.72]  [5, 73.83]
```

Now melt it according to whether the column is a number

```
melted = as_lists.melt(
    id_vars=[c for c in as_lists.columns if not isinstance(c, int)], 
    value_vars=[c for c in as_lists.columns if isinstance(c, int)]).dropna()
```

Split the last column, and append it:

```
final = pd.merge(df, melted)[['sports_name', 'player_name', 'player_country', 'value']]
>>> final.head()
    sports_name player_name player_country  value
0   football    XYZ US  [1, 62.58]
1   football    XYZ US  [2, 25.34]
2   football    XYZ US  [3, 88.35]
3   football    XYZ US  [4, 59.39]
4   football    ABC US  [1, 56.61]
```

Now just drop bad rows:

```
final = final[~final.value.astype(str).str.contains(r'-|NA')]
```

final.head()

and split the last column:

```
>>> pd.concat([
    final, 
    pd.DataFrame(final.value.values.tolist(), index=final.index, columns=['player_match', 'player_average'])],
axis=1).drop('value', axis=1)
    sports_name player_name player_country  player_match    player_average
0   football    XYZ US  1   62.58
1   football    XYZ US  2   25.34
2   football    XYZ US  3   88.35
3   football    XYZ US  4   59.39
4   football    ABC US  1   56.61
5   football    ABC US  2   52.63
7   football    ABC US  4   44.32
8   football    ABC US  5   39.69
9   cricket PQR IND 1   98.73
10  cricket PQR IND 2   72.62
11  cricket PQR IND 3   71.53
12  cricket PQR IND 4   73.72
13  cricket LMN IND 1   72.52
14  cricket LMN IND 2   71.82
16  cricket LMN IND 4   62.72
17  cricket LMN IND 5   73.83
```

Comment: Your suggestions are not working properly for me. It is going in wrong direction at the end of the results. In your answer can you show me the complete final dataframe? It is providing wrong output for me

Comment: How to allow "player_average" value as int as well and "float" as well?

Comment: You can always do things like `final.player_average = final.player_average.astype(float)`.

Comment: Not like that. I am getting empty dataframe after applying melt function. data is like: 6 digits in player match and 4 digits in player_average. Any suggestion to handle this situation?

Comment: Are you getting that on the data in the question, or on other data? The more reproducible the problem it is, the easier to solve. Your edit suggestion, for example, makes me wonder whether your indexes are not simply running integers.

Comment: Solved that issue. Is any substitute available for as_lists = pd.concat(
    [df, pd.DataFrame(df.player_average.apply(ast.literal_eval).tolist())],
    axis=1).drop('player_average', axis=1). I am facing performance issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing of which I can think. It's structurally changing the dimension, which is always more expensive.